# Metro-like font for website use

Tags: css, fonts

What font would you advise (free for commercial use) for a website styled like Metro Windows 8? Would be best if it's on Google Fonts etc.

Comment: Fonts are chosen by the browser, not on the server.

Comment: Why do I find it unlikely that a Metro style font (created by *Microsoft*) would be available on *Google* Fonts?

Comment: try dafont.com for font downloads.

Answer (score 45):

The font used with the 'Metro' branding is [Segoe UI](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=331). Unfortunately, as others have mentioned, it isn't available as a free download.

Though, even if you happen to have Segoe, other users of your webapp might not. Consequently, for it to display consistently to your users you would need to `@font-face` it. But, alas, due to licensing, it'd be against the law to simply host it on your server and font-face it. The only legal way to use Segoe UI is to [purchase a license](http://www.ascendercorp.com/font/segoe-ui/) to use it.

But you want a free option, so let's look at some Segoe lookalikes.

Segoe UI is incredibly similar to [Frutiger](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/frutiger/) – so similar, in fact, that [Microsoft was taken to court by Linotype over it](http://arstechnica.com/uncategorized/2006/04/6517-2/) – but, of course, that font isn't free either.

If you specifically wanted to use a Google Font, the popular [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans) might be your best bet, though there are a few noticeable differences between it and Segoe.

You might have more luck finding fonts that aren't all that well-known but are heavily inspired by the famous, expensive ones (some might call them shameless rip-offs). Two examples are [CartoGothic Std](http://www.fontsite.com/2129/cartogothic-std/) and [WeblySleek UI](http://www.dafont.com/weblysleek-ui.font). For most users, you'll find that the differences between these fonts are imperceptible. And you're in luck, as, at the time of writing this, it happens that you're free to host these fonts yourself to provide them via `@font-face` (Disclaimer: I recommend you read the licenses for details before doing this. They are subject to change).

Want a quick comparison? Here are some images, as rendered in Photoshop on OSX. The font sizes are all about 10pt. And they're all set to normal or book weight.

As you can see, the biggest difference between the first three fonts and Open Sans is the lower case *g*. I'm sure there are more differences between the upper case letters, and I encourage you to explore those details.

Segoe UI

[Segoe UI http://jmeas.com/stackoverflow/segoe.jpg](http://jmeas.com/stackoverflow/segoe.jpg)

Frutiger

[Segoe UI http://jmeas.com/stackoverflow/frutiger.jpg](http://jmeas.com/stackoverflow/frutiger.jpg)

CartoGothic STD

[Cartogothic STD http://jmeas.com/stackoverflow/cartogothic.jpg](http://jmeas.com/stackoverflow/cartogothic.jpg)

WeblySleek UI

[Cartogothic STD http://so.jmeas.com/weblysleek.jpg](http://so.jmeas.com/weblysleek.jpg)

Open Sans

[Open Sans http://jmeas.com/stackoverflow/open-sans.jpg](http://jmeas.com/stackoverflow/open-sans.jpg)

I hope one of those fits your needs.

Comment: This one also looks pretty nice. Maybe you could add it to your answer:
http://www.dafont.com/weblysleek-ui.font

Comment: Good suggestion, @andreas. A cursory glance at it did suggest to me it'd be a good Segoe UI replacement. I'll check it out further and update my answer.

Comment: I tested it on my website and it looks nearly the same. I also tested Open Sans but I wasn't completely satisfied until I have seen that other font. ;)

Comment: @andreas, yeah, Open Sans is only vaguely reminiscent of Segoe UI, at best. I really only included it as an option since the asker mentioned  Google Fonts in the question. CartoGothic and Webly Sleek seem to be much better alternatives!

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be exactly like metro you could use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ and upload a font.

**NOTE:** Make sure you have a license for the font if using fontsquirrel, as mentioned in the comments.

Otherwise maybe **Helvetica** or **Arial**. Those are the closets Web Safe fonts that I can think of.

The new metro font is a Sans Serif font and Arial has always been the Sans Serif font most closely related to Windows.

Also I am using this google font with a metro font logo and I feel like they are pretty similar.

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400' rel='stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Also check out Microsoft's website. They are using this font family.. `font-family: segoe ui, verdana, arial, sans-serif;`

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/home

Also Check out this post, seems to be very similar. 
https://superuser.com/questions/336031/what-font-is-used-on-windows-8-or-windows-phone-7

Comment: You can't just upload any font to Font Squirrel. You need a license to use it, and that license has to allow use as a webfont.